# How to get response object from POST request?

Tags: spring, apache, http, post, request

It is a Spring application, I'm trying to make a POST request and get back a response.

At server side I have this

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
Test testmethod(@RequestBody Test test) {
    test.setValue("test");
return test;
}
```

At client side I have the post method which should return the Test object. I use JSON for ecoding.

```
public Object post(String url1, Test test) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(login);

    try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url1);

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(jsonInString);
        input.setContentType("application/json");
        postRequest.setEntity(input);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

        //read the object from the response, how to do that?
        //responseObject = ?????

        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
return responseObject;
}
```

And

```
Test s = new Test;
Test s=(Test)post("http://localhost:8081/basic-web-app/test",s);
```

My problem is that i don't know hot to get the Test object from the response. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
String responseAsString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: But I don't need a String,  need a Test object.

Comment: You send json so it is a String. Just use some JSON to Object converter